# Autocomplete only city name List using Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I use the following code for my website but it does not work. What is the problem? I've included the snippet for error reporting.

```html
 <head>
 <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places" type="text/javascript">
</script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function initialize() {
            var options = {
                types: ['(cities)'],
                componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}
            };

            var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input , options);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <div class = "row">
        <input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="on">
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: No i want only City name .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `sensor=false&amp;` from your script's `src` attribute and instead add your API key:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
```

The following worked for me:

```
<body>
  <input id="searchTextField" />
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
  <script>
    function initialize() {
      var options = {
        types: ['(cities)'],
        componentRestrictions: {
          country: "us"
        }
      };

      var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
      var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: For this to work, with your google API key, you need to enable both the Google Maps Javascript API and the Places API.

Comment: Can we test this in keylesss?

Comment: Do you mean without the API key?

Comment: I've just tested this and it displays the city as well as state and country. Shouldn't it display only the city?

Comment: Sorry @default123, I have not worked with the API in a while so I'm not sure. I hope you were able to figure it out.